# Using Group By as part of a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to eliminate certain records from a dataset using SQL Server. The title of my post may be inaccurate, as a better solution may exist than what I have in mind.

In my query, I am selecting from Table A, and the rows that I want to end up with should meet the following criteria:

1. All rows where A.ItemNumber = B.ItemNumber
2. All rows where A.ItemNumber <> B.ItemNumber AND that row's Task value does not have another row that meets criteria #1.

So for the below example:

1. Gives us ItemNumber 102, 104, 106 rows.
2. Gives us ItemNumber 105 row.
   100, 101 are removed from dataset because their Task (1) is associated with Table B at ItemNumber 102. Same for 103 with Task (2) being associated at ItemNumber 104.

```
Table A
Task    ItemNumber
1          100
1          101
1          102
2          103
2          104
3          105
4          106

Table B
ItemNumber       Data
102              aaa
104              bbb
106              ccc
```

My initial thought was to load Table A into a temp table, LEFT JOIN with Table B, and DELETE FROM {temp table} WHERE (data IS NULL AND {insert some kind of grouping logic here}). But I have been completely unable to figure out a grouping logic that will work for the problem. I spent the weekend hoping a solution would come to me, but am now giving in and seeking advice.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: The desired result is actually to remove the rows from Table A that don't meet the listed criteria. ItemNumber 100, 101, and 103 are essentially fake Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a CTE that meets the 1st condition and UNION ALL to return the rest of the rows:

```
with cte as (
  select a.*
  from TableA a
  where exists (select 1 from TableB where ItemNumber = a.ItemNumber)
)
select * from cte
union all
select a.* from TableA a
where not exists (select 1 from cte where Task = a.Task)
order by Task
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9fd0905a689440180047f0ebdd50ac72).
Results:

```
Task    ItemNumber
1       102
2       104
3       105
4       106
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA AS A
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B ON A.ItemNumber = B.ItemNumber
WHERE B.ItemNumber IS NOT NULL -- critera 1
  OR  (B.ItemNumber IS NULL AND B.ItemNumber NOT IN
           (SELECT A.ItemNumber 
            FROM TABLEA AS A
            JOIN TABLEB AS B ON A.ItemNumber = B.ItemNumber)) -- criteria 2
```

Comment: Am I reading this incorrectly, or will the NOT IN subquery return 102, 104, 106? Which would then return us basically the full LEFT JOIN (At least with the dataset in the example tables)?

Comment: @boc4life -- depends on the data.

Answer (score 1):

One way to phrase this puts all the filtering logic in the `where` clause:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where exists (select 1
              from tableb b
              where b.itemnumber = a.itemnumber
             ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from tableb b2 join
                       tablea a2
                       on b2.itemnumber = a2.itemnumber
                  where a2.task = a.task
                 );
```